# Power Shell issue with create user

Tags: powershell

what is here wrong with create a local user?
$user New-LocalUser -Name "test" -NoPassword -AccountNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword -FullName "Test Admin" -Description "Test User Admin " | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true

Comment: Well, what happens and what do you expect to happen? Do you get any error messages, if you do, what do they say? [Edit] that info into the question. Do not add those as comments as those are hard to read and ephemereal anyway.

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `=` after the first `$user` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because of set-Localuser is added in user creation itself.

```
$user = New-LocalUser -Name "test" -NoPassword -AccountNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword -FullName "Test Admin" -Description "Test User Admin " 
$user | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $user
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $user
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you pipe the returned object of `New-LocalUser` directly through to `Set-LocalUser`, the capturing variable `$user` will be `$null`.
As you can see in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1#outputs), the Set-LocalUser cmdlet returns **no output**

The fix is easy: seperate these two commands in two separate lines.

Also, I would recommend using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters to help keep the code readable as opposed to using extremely long code lines.

```
# create a Hashtable with all parameters and their values 
# for use with the New-LocalUser cmdlet
$userParams = @{
    Name                     = "test"
    FullName                 = "Test Admin"
    Description              = "Test User Admin"
    AccountNeverExpires      = $true
    NoPassword               = $true
    UserMayNotChangePassword = $true
}

# create the user and afterwards set another property to the user object
$user = New-LocalUser @userParams
$user | Set-LocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true

Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $user
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -Member $user
```

<sup>Setting `-PasswordNeverExpires $true` shouldn't be necessary anyway, because you created the user with option `-NoPassWord` AND `UserMayNotChangePassword`</sup>

Comment: Ok I will test it and let you know